# How to Insert Large Binary Data(Above 32KB ) in to oracle table using Procedure / Inline / C#

Tags: c#, plsql, oracle11g, blob

I am facing issue when I try to upload the data which is more than 32kb size. here is my source.

Query:
     INSERT ("DllName", "DllData", "DllVersion", "AssemblyId")
         VALUES (v_codepluginname, v_dlldata, v_dllversion, v_assemblyid);

v_dlldata is the Binary Data. Data type in the DB is BLOB

I am using Oracle.ExecuteNonQuery();

Please let me if there is any solution.

Answer (score 1):

Our code probably uses implicit conversion to RAW datatype.

Oracle LOBS have different semantics, than other dattypes. And also Oracle treates them differently than other databases. Imagine that a BLOB is in fact a file handle (it's called LOB locator) created on the side of the DB server. Create a procedure, which creates an empty LOB, and then it returns it to a caller:

```
create or replace procedure store_lob (i_DllName in VARCHAR2, o_DllData in out BLOB)
as
begin 
  insert into t1(DDL_NAME, DDL_DATA) VALUES(i_DDLNAME, EMPTY_BLOB) 
  RETURNING DDR_DATA into o_DDLDate);
end;
```

Then when our procedure returns, you have a socket, where you can write a file content.
You can even start an async thread, and write the file asynchonously, while you use the same db connection for something else. You can append to a lob locator until you issue the commit.

This approach seems to be a little bit over-engeneered, but on the other hand it supports producer-cunsummer design pattern, and no one (neither the app, neither the DB) has to hold the whole file content in a RAM.